# Установка CentOS в VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Скачал образ с официального сайта.
Когда я пытаюсь выполнить устновку с ISO образа в VirtualBox'e, мне предлагают на выбор 3 пункта:

- Установка
- Проверка и установка
- решение проблем

Пробовал первые 2 пункта, но после их выбора висит черный экран.
В чем может быть проблема? Никаких ошибок не вылетает...

Comment: битность (32 или 64) основной и устанавливаемой систем совпадает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Битность основной ОС 64, с официального сайта качал образ CentOS и на нем было написано х86, х64. Как я понял, он должен быть универсальным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо разрешить виртуализацию. Если не ошибаюсь, CentOS хотел её независимо от битности (хотя, по идее, она обязательна только для x64):

> Настройки -> Система -> Ускорение -> Аппаратная виртуализация: Включить VT-x/AMD-V

Если флажок задисейблен, то надо сначала разрешить её в биосе.

Если в биосе она разрешена, а основная ОС - Win8+, то проблема в конфликте со стандартной виртуализацией Windows - её надо отключить (не знаю как).

---

UPDATE: Что-то я запутался, возможно, нужна не та опция, а

> Настройки -> Система -> Процессор -> Дополнительные возможности: Включить PAE/NX

В общем, надо обратить внимание на эти 2 опции и если одна из них задисейблена, то на биос и виртуализацию Windows.

---

Попробовал установить (на Win7)

1. По торренту http://mirror.satellite-service.ru/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1503-01.torrent скачал iso-образ
2. Создал новую виртуалку, указав Linux Ubuntu x64.
3. Запустил установку, установил.
4. Перезагрузил виртуалку.
5. Подожнал примерно минуту с чёрным мигающим курсором.
6. Мельком видел какую-то ошибку, потом пополз прогрессбар.
7. Загрузилась консольная оболочка. Вроде работает...

Вот скриншот с параметрами виртуалки: http://s017.radikal.ru/i400/1505/ca/7d80a5497d9e.png
Да, PAE/NX не понадобился. Я оставил все настройки кроме видеопамяти в дефаултном состоянии.

Кстати, вспомнил, что создание виртуалки тоже важно. при выборе типа задаются какие-то необратимые параметры (по крайней мере те, которые нельзя поменять через интерфейс настроек). Например, если виртуалка создавалась с указанием XP, то сетевой инталлятор (основанный на Win8) на ней не запускался.

Comment: Все верно, ничего вы не напутали.

Comment: Все равно что-то не работает... Изначально у меня стоял флажок PAE/NX в Virutual Box . Полез в BIOS врубил виртуализацию, попробовал установить CentOS, но ничего не произошло. Отключил флажок в Virtual Box и опять ничего...

Comment: Оба флажка можешь включить? Какая ОС?

Comment: С обоими флажками(BIOS+Virtual Box) тоже не пашет=(. Основная ось Windows 10

Comment: XP к примеру работает в Virtual Box...

Comment: Встроенную виртуализацию Windows (которая существует начиная с Win8) отключать пробовал?

Comment: Это Hyper-V если не ошибаюсь? А где его отрубать?

Comment: Да, вроде оно. Я ж в ответе написал, что не знаю, как. Но год назад в Win 8.1 оно с VirtualBox'ом конфликтовало. Там дисейблился флажок, как если бы виртуализация была отключена в биосе, хотя она была включена. Я только знаю как факт, что его отключение помогло. Предположил, что сейчас, хотя флажок и установлен, какой-то конфликт с ней всё равно может быть. А CentOS я когда-то давно пытался ставить на XP - он у меня явно потребовал, чтобы виртуализация была включена (не помню точно фразу). Правда, я тогда на него забил и ничего делать не стал. Кстати, а почему нужен именно CentOS на виртуалке?

Comment: Сейчас попробую поставить, но у меня Win7

Comment: @iluxa1810, дополнил ответ.

Comment: У меня, кстати, почему-то Virtual Box не предлагает x64 варианты создания виртуалок, хотя процессор intel I7

Comment: @iluxa1810 Эм.. Т. е. ты ожидаешь, что в 32-битной виртуалке запустится 64-битный CentOS? Не запустится. Кстати, в варианте с включенным Hyper-V она тоже не предлагала. Отключи наконец его.

Comment: Спасибо. После отключения Hyper-v и выставления Linux x64. ОС поставилась. Подскажите, а как я могу запустить CentOS в графическом режиме? Сейчас он у меня запускается в режиме командной строки.

Comment: @iluxa1810, не знаю. Я не линуксоид. Гугл вроде что-то знает. Кстати, из линуксов мне Mint нравится.

Comment: Кстати, было бы логично ответ отметить, раз уж CentOS запустился ;)

Answer (score 0):

У меня была таже проблема на другом процессоре (AMD Athlon 64) с обратной попыткой поставить на 64-битную систему 32-битный вариант CentOS. Тоже подумал, что по названию там должна быть 32-битная версия. А я не вижу смысла запускать 64-бита на тестовой виртуалке с выделением минимума памяти.

Решилось также: переключением настройки "RedHat (32-bit)" в 64. Остальные настройки для запуска роли не играют, PAE не нужен, в БИОС лезть не надо (да и не помню там такой опции на моём компе).
Настройка переключает оптимизацию среды виртуалки под тип операционки.